# List interval comparison

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to make a very long program much shorter by making it concise, because I need to modify it to run through several kinds of reports.  Basically, it loads a list from a report in excel, and then checks to see if those values are above or below control limits.  I tried using an interval comparison to see if any value in my list was not between the control limits, but that did not work.  Instead, I had to go with a little bit longer method that did work.  Can someone please explain to me why the second method shown below does not work?  There are no errors, but it does not find the failed tests like the first one does.

```
############### This is the same between the two methods #############
#Loading my list with the variables to be checked
GtimeList = [37, 37, 37, 32, 32, 32, 
Gtime3b, GtimeAveb]
GT = 0
#Make sure these are numbers
if any(isinstance(x, str) for x in GtimeList):
    continue

######## Method one works fine, but I want it more concise    ############
#Check to see if any of the variables are not between 10 to 35

elif any(10 > x for x in GtimeList) or any(35 < x for x in GtimeList):
    GT = 'Gel Time'

########     Method two, this is how I want it to work            ########
#Check to see if any of the variables are not between 10 to 35

elif any(10 > x > 35 for x in GtimeList):
    GT = 'Gel Time'
```

Comment: Your first condition checks if x<10 or x<35. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Because `10 > x > 35` means `10 > x` AND `x > 35` which is always False obviously

Comment: 10 > x > 35 its same as 10 > x and x > 35. Understanding that 35 > 10, x can not be true because x can not be fewer than 10 and greater than 35

Comment: That makes a lot of sense!  So that isn't really an 'OR' statement, its an 'AND' statement.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is maybe this:

```
any(x not in range(10,36) for x in GtimeList)
```

Comment: That does depend on the values being whole numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of more of a logic question than a programming question. Both of your code snippets have two conditions for each value, for a total of 2n conditions. Your first code snippet just needs one out of those 2n conditions to be true. Your second requires two of them to be true, and needs the two to be for the same value. You should replace the `any` in the second code with `not all`.

Basically, your first code is "∃ x: 10 > x  and ∃ x: 35 < x", while your second is ∃x: (10 > x and x < 35). You're turning "or" into "and". Using logic rules, we can do the following:

∃ x: 10 > x  or ∃ x: 35 < x ≡ 
not (∀ x: 10 > x) or not (∀ x: 35 < x) ≡ 
not ((∀ x: 10 > x) and (∀ x: 35 < x)) ≡ 
not ((∀ x: 10 > x and 35 < x))

You could also do `min(GtimeList) < 10 or max(GtimeList) > 35`.

And as a side note regarding your `isinstance(x, str)` check, it's generally a better idea to check whether everything *is* what you want it to be, rather than it *isn't* what you don't want it to be. What if `x` is something other than a string or a number, such as a list?